# Creating a set in dictionary

Tags: python, linux, windows, dictionary, set

I need to create a set in a dictionary.

```
dicInvertedIndex = {}
docID = 1

for i in string:
  if condition:
    docID += 1
  dicInvertedIndex[i] = [1, set(docID)]
```

And i have a error:

```
dicInvertedIndex[i] = [1, set(docID)]
 TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Before I tried this, I created a list in the dictionary and it works.

```
dicInvertedIndex[i] = [ 1 , [ docID ] ]
```

And it works. I need to create a dictionary with keys of my documents and values of (`int`, `set()`)

like `dic["awake"] = [5, {2, 30, 99, 234}]`

Originally I used a list, but it's slow, and i want to use a set.

Comment: `not iterable` sounds like it's the `for` loop. Double check what's in `string`.

Comment: You should ask about how to solve your base problem instead of why your attempted solution isn't working.

Comment: ok, thanks. i ask another question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `set()` constructor takes an iterable.  `docID` is an integer and therefore not iterable.

Two workarounds are

```
{docID}
```

or

```
set([docID])
```

Answer (score 2):

The argument to `set()` is expected to be iterable, just put `docID` in a list when you pass it:

```
dicInvertedIndex[i] = [1, set([docID])]
```

Comment: thanks. Is there a more suitable storage structure for my use.
I need a symbol frequency (count) and where meets

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what you are trying to accomplish, but I see your bug. The set constructor requires an iterable, and you are passing an integer.  Here's the fix:

```
dicInvertedIndex[i] = [1, set([docID])]
```

Notice that docID is inside square brackets.